# How to access the components of an untitled window using apple script

Tags: applescript

I am new to SO.Plz. guide me if i am wrong.I'm writing an apple UI script to click a button of an mac app,but the problem is that the window that contains the button has no name(empty string "",got from UIElementInspector).Please help me out how to refer the window.

Answer (score 0):

You can usually use an index, for example **window 2**.  A list of items can be viewed in the event log by using something like

```
tell application "System Events" to get windows of application process "foo"
```

Comment: You will need to use the hierarchy shown in the UIElement Inspector, possibly creating the window first if it is something like a dialog or panel.